# Is a bard's use of Bardic Inspiration still expended if the target can't hear them?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, conditions, bard, hearing

What happens if a bard tries to give a target a Bardic Inspiration, but that target happens to be unable to hear the bard due to deafness or a [Silence](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Silence#content) spell. Does the bard lose one of their bardic inspiration uses anyway?

Comment: Are there any other class features that are not expended just because the target is immune to the effect?

Comment: @krb Maybe. I'm not sure if a paladin's lay on hands ability expends points if the target is unable to be healed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You can't use Bardic Inspiration if the target is deafened

The Bardic Inspiration feature says (emphasis mine):

> You can inspire others through stirring words or music. **To do so**, you use a bonus action on your turn to choose one creature other than yourself within 60 feet of you **who can hear you**.

So, the use is not wasted because you are unable to target that creature with your inspiration.

There's no reason to assume the the feature would behave like a spell when it isn't one (i.e. the use would be wasted).

Jeremy Crawford – D&D lead rules designer – has clarified many times that assumptions like this shouldn't be done. For example:

> "A rule in D&D does only what it says it does—nothing more. Beware of creating rules interactions that the rules themselves don't make." ([source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1188159800288239616))
>
> "Beware of claims that a rule does something mentioned nowhere in that rule or elsewhere in the core books. There aren't secret rules." ([source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95021/discussion-between-cubic-and-kuerten).

Answer (score 1):

## Unclear according to core rules

There is no rule governing this situation in the core rules, similar to the situation with spells. The closest thing are the (optional) rules on casting spells with an invalid target from XGtE, which say that a spell with invalid targets is still cast and a spell slot is used, but there is no visible effect.

You could rule Bardic Inspiration similarly - you still expended the effort to inspire someone, you just failed because the target couldn't properly perceive your attempt at inspiration.

(As the other answer stated, you could also rule that the bard is unable to even make the attempt; you could run with that, although that'd arguably require you to always know whether or not someone can hear you, which isn't a bard power I'm aware of.)

See also JC's answer to whether or not a spell can be cast against an invalid target and whether or not that expends a spell slot:

> No rule governs this situation. Xanathar's Guide does include one, however.

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/895045804309716992

Since abilities aren't governed by different targeting rules than spells, arguably the same reasoning applies.